# AngularJS $http.post data doesn't get to server

Tags: jquery, django, angularjs, http-post

I've just started building my first angularjs project and i got stuck with $http.post. Whatever data I send, it won't get intercepted by the server (Django). I've seen many posts saying that i have to change the Content-Type headere to:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Did that, didn't help.

when i started to look a little deeper, comparing $http and Jquery's $.post, I noticed that when the data is sent with $http, this is the Form Data that is sent:

```
{"first_prop":"789564","second_prop":"Foo","third_prop":"Bar"}:
```

with the semi-colon at the end.

When I send it with $.post (and it works), this is what gets sent:

```
first_prop:789564
second_prop:Foo
third_prop:Bar
```

So, they don't send information the same way.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong the $http.post?

Here is what my code:

```
$http.post('pakashnotifier/addSlave', {
first_prop:"789564",
second_prop:"Foo",
third_prop:"Bar"
})
```

**UPDATE**
I've noticed now that with $http.post, the post gets intercepted as a GET on server.

If anybody can help, that'd be great :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
$http.post('pakashnotifier/addSlave', {
    data : {
        first_prop:"789564",
        second_prop:"Foo",
        third_prop:"Bar"
    }
})
```

If working with django, it appears that would work using jquery $param

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/url/', 
    data: $.param({
        first_prop:"789564",
        second_prop:"Foo",
        third_prop:"Bar"
    })
})
```

Comment: Tried it and it didn't help, I noticed now that the request is sent as a POST but django interecepts it as a GET.

Comment: updated the answer for matching with django. That should work

Comment: Thanks! that helped a lot. Weird thing is, the $http.post sometimes get intercepted as GET posts and something as POST. anyway, it also never get intercepted as an ajax request

Comment: @sid802 you said that sometimes POST requests are received as GET. I seem to have the same issue, did you figure our why it did so? And even better, how to fix it? :P

Comment: @sid802 you said that sometimes POST requests are received as GET. I seem to have the same issue, did you figure our why it did so? And even better, how to fix it? :P

Comment: I don't really remember what i did back then, but something similar happened to me a few weeks ago and everything i send through POST got sent in the body of the request. If it's there, make sure your Content-Type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and that should

Answer (score 0):

First, defualt transformations in $http is using JSON. You can check this in 'Default Transformation' from API document [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), you need to set this according your server if it need to accept the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Then here is my form data which I find in Chrome DevTools:

```
{"first_prop":"789564","second_prop":"Foo","third_prop":"Bar"}
```

I haven't get the semi-colon at the end.